# How to perform Multi output regression using RoBERTa?

Tags: pytorch, regression, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have a problem statement where I want to predict multiple continuous outputs using a text input. I tried using 'robertaforsequenceclassification' from HuggingFace library. But the documentation states that when the number of outputs in the final layer is more than 1, a cross entropy loss is used automatically as mentioned here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.2.0/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.
But I want to use an RMSE loss in a regression setting with two classes in the final layer. How would one go about modifying it?

Comment: Hey Shreyas, were you able to do the regression task using bert, how was the result? Can you give some reference to the code? Thank you.

Comment: @AnilKumar Did you find a way to perform multi-outputs regression? I'm stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BertForSequenceClassification` is a small wrapper that wraps the `BERTModel`.

It calls the models, takes the pooled output (the second member of the output tuple), and applies a classifier over it. The code is here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L1168

The simplest solution is writing your own simple wrapper class (based on the `BertForSequenceClassification` class) hat will do the regression that will do the regression with the loss you like.

Comment: Thanks! Just did that :)

Comment: @Shreyas Did it work correctly? I'm trying to do the same and will greatly appreciate any feedback or code snippets. Thanks!